# ASP.NET MVC twitter/myspace style routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

This is my first post after being a long-time lurker - so please be gentle :-)

I have a website similar to twitter, in that people can sign up and choose a 'friendly url', so on my site they would have something like:

mydomain.com/benjones

I also have root level static pages such as:

mydomain.com/about

and of course my homepage:

mydomain.com/

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 2 (in fact I just started today) and I've set up the following routes to try and achieve the above.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("images/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("About", "about",
            new { controller = "Common", action = "About" }
        );

        // User profile sits at root level so check for this before displaying the homepage
        routes.MapRoute("UserProfile", "{url}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Profile", url = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute("Home", "",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
```

For the most part this works fine, however, my homepage is not being triggered! Essentially, when you browser to mydomain.com, it seems to trigger the User Profile route with an empty {url} parameter and so the homepage is never reached! Any ideas on how I can show the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not swap the bottom two routes?

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to do the trick. In addition to the "about" page, I'll be having "contact", "help" etc. Is there a way of programmatically finding out what routes are already in use so that when users sign up for a username, they will be prevented from taking an application url, or do I need to manually hardcode in a blacklist of urls?

Answer (score 2):

Know this question was asked a while back but I was just looking to do the same sort of thing and couldn't find any answer that quite solved it for me so I figured I'd add my 2 cents for others that may also look to do the same thing in future.

The problem with the proposed solution above (as mentioned in Astrofaes' comment) is that you would need to create static routes for every controller in your assembly. So in the end I ended up using a custom route constraint to check whether or not a controller exists in the executing assembly that could handle the request. If there is then return a false on the match so that the request will be handled by another route.

```
public class NotControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<Type> Controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Controller));

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return Controllers.Where(c => c.Name == values["id"] + "Controller").Count() == 0;
    }
}
```

Routes can then be set up as follows:

```
 routes.MapRoute("User", "{id}", new { controller = "User", action = "Index" }, new { notController = new NotControllerConstraint() });

 routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: This worked pretty good for me. Just want to suggest one change. The version above doesn't work if your Controllers inherit from a custom controller class instead of the base 'Controller' class. It can be fixed like this:  `private static readonly IEnumerable<Type> Controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => typeof (Controller).IsAssignableFrom(t));`

Comment: Also, guess I might as well add this, kind of picky, but the return statement for Match can be simplified as well. Same result though.: `return Controllers.All(c => c.Name != values["id"] + "Controller");`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that swapping the routes works, is because the {url} route doesn't have a constraint on it against empty strings (which is what your last route is). As a result, it will match the empty string first as it's higher in the route table.

With that in mind, you can either [add constraints](http://www.aspworkshops.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx) or add your specifically named routes higher in the routes table, or use the default catch all routes that mvc gives you to start with.

If you want to know which routes are matching at any given moment, then you can use the [Route Debugger](http://helios.ca/2009/05/26/aspnet-mvc-route-debugging/) from Phil Haack.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to implement same style of url for my MVC 1.0 application.

I have [implemented that](http://balasingam.com/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-twittermyspace-url-style-routing) with information from this post and [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-route-constraints.aspx) by Guy Burstein.

Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simlar setup as below:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Common",
        "common/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "common", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );


    routes.MapRoute(
        "Dynamic",
        "{id}",
        new { controller = "dynamic", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

This allows me to be flexible and have the routes

mysite.com/

mysite.com/common/contact/
mysite.com/common/about/
mysite.com/common/{wildcard}/

mysite.com/{anything}